# Prove existence of formula of adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

In functional analysis, let $Dom A$ be Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.
Let A be self-adjoint operator, $A = A^*$, $m_A > 0$. Here $m_A = \inf_{u \in Dom A} \frac{(Au, u)}{|u|^2_\mathcal{H}}$. $E$ is spectral measure which maps Borel sets of real line to set of bounded operators, i.e. $E: \mathcal{B} \rightarrow B(\mathcal{H})$.

There exists such a formula $A = \int_{\mathcal{R}} \lambda \, dE_A(\lambda) = \int_{m_A}^{\infty} \lambda \, dE_A(\lambda)$. How to prove this?

Comment: There is a general formula where the integral ranges over all the real line. Your assumption implies that for $\lambda<m_A$ the operator $\lambda I-A$ is invertible, therefore the integral ranges from $m_A$ to $\infty.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Actually I did not understand what that $dE_A(\lambda)$ means in detail. Does it mean integrate over set of resolvents s.t. $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc And where does the general formula come from? Can you write an answer?

Comment: You can look up textbooks listed in references in  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem For example Reed, Simon book